# Show first 15 characters + '...' if a field is longer than 15 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

If character length exceeds 15 characters then I want to show the first fifteen characters plus the `...` symbol.

For example, if the field `adtitle` contains:

> sri laxmi narasimha agency.

`adtitle` exceeds 15 characters, so the output should look like:

> sri laxmi naras...

If `adtitle` does not exceed 15 characters, it should display the value normally. Can anyone suggest how to write this query? I assume the `LEFT()` function is needed, my current query is below.

```
select 
    adtitle,category left(adtitle,15)+'...'adtitle,left(category,15)+'...' category 
from postad
```

Comment: What database are you using?  I am guessing SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This query will be helpful.

```
select CASE WHEN Len(adtitle) > 15
                THEN left(adtitle,15) +'...'
                ELSE adtitle
        END AS adtitle
 from postad
```

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional logic:

```
select (case when len(adtitle) > 15 then left(adtitle,15) + '...'
             else adtitle
        end) as new_adtitle
from postad
```